why amplify didn't send ses email
I created a script in node.js to send email with aws-ses.
My script:
import express from 'express';

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
const app: express.Application = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'index.html'));
});

// @ts-ignore
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    send(req.body.name, req.body.address, req.body.text)
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Villa app listening on port ${port}!`);
});

// @ts-ignore
function send(name, address, text) {

    // Create sendEmail params
    let params = {
        Destination: {
            /* required */
            CcAddresses: [
                "xxxx",
                /* more items */
            ],
            ToAddresses: [
                address,
                /* more items */
            ],
        },
        Message: {
            /* required */
            Body: {
                /* required */
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: text,
                },
                Text: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: text,
                },
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: "UTF-8",
                Data: "Nouveau Message de la Residence Bloc H",
            },
        },
        Source: "xxx" /* required */,
        ReplyToAddresses: [
            "xxx",
            /* more items */
        ],
    };

    // Create the promise and SES service object
    let sendPromise = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: "2010-12-01" })
        .sendEmail(params)
        .promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states
    sendPromise
        // @ts-ignore
        .then(function (data) {
            console.log(data.MessageId);
        })
        // @ts-ignore
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err, err.stack);
        });
}

Locally it work's because i created a user with this policies AmazonSesSendingAccess and saved the security credentials on my computer.
I created an app with amplify and added my code.
I created a role with IAM with those two policies:
AdministratorAccess-Amplify and AmazonSESFullAccess and added this roles as service role to my amplify app.
But into the amplify app on the aws cloud i can't send the email.

Do you have a specific error in the logs? also try to assume the Amplify service role locally and test wether it can send or no, better than testing with another user. you can do that with : aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/YOUR_ROLE" --role-session-name test-session and then run the aws ses send-email command
